# Обнуление статического динамически созданого масива

Tags: c++

В приведенной функции я создаю статический массив. Каким образом его можно единажды обнулить, при первом входе в функцию?

```
typedef unsigned char uchar;
typedef unsigned long long int ullong;

// Рекурентный алгоритм нахождения F(n) 
// F(n) - число Фибоначи, n - порядковый номер
ullong Fibonachi_Recursion_With_Memory(const uchar &_n)
{
  static ullong *const M = new ullong[_n + 1]; // Динамически выделеный массив (который нужно обнулить)

  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// - (мой способ)
  static bool emptyVector(false);

  if(!emptyVector)
  {
    for(uchar i = 0; i <= _n; i++) 
      M[i] = 0;
    emptyVector = true;
  }
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  if(_n <= 2)
    return 1;

  if(M[_n] != 0) 
    return M[_n];

  return
    M[_n] = Fibonachi_Recursion_With_Memory(_n - 1) + Fibonachi_Recursion_With_Memory(_n - 2);
}
```

Comment: Я что-то ваш код не понял.
Ведь если вызвать ваш код 2 раза, например `Fibonachi_Recursion_With_Memory(1); Fibonachi_Recursion_With_Memory(5);` то получится бред, потому что массив во втором случае будет размером в 1 элемент.

Comment: @zenden2k, опа, прогадал, спасибо за поправку)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Легко!

```
static ullong *const M = new ullong[_n + 1]();
```

Будет работать и в C++03

Comment: Насколько мне известно, с массивами в C++ 03 это не работает. Такой синтаксис можно использовать только для скалярных объектов создаваемых оператором new.

Comment: VS2008 http://fs1.directupload.net/images/150630/aos2qyby.png
слева без скобочек, справа со скобочками

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, это работает, вижла 12 ))) удивлен, приятно)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, так действительно можно делать - [enSO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204176/how-to-initialise-memory-with-new-operator-in-c)

Comment: @neitron C VS 12 это не проблема, так как этот компилятор заявлен, как поддерживающий стандарт C++ 2011.

Comment: @ixSci  Возможно. Уже приходится вспоминать, что работало, а что нет.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow. что касается поддержки с++ 11, то наверное мне следует обновится, так как все нововведения с++ 11 у меня не работают. (не воспринимаются, требует правильного синтаксиса, выдеет ерроры)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow VS 12 не поддерживает списки инициализации, смотрите сравнительную таблицу.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh567368.aspx

Comment: @neitron Я сторонник того, чтобы всегда стараться использовать обновленные версии компиляторов, так как всегда существует задержка с поддержкой стандарта тем или иным компилятором. И используя обновленную версию, вы просто стараетесь наверстать упущенное, так как разработчики компиляторов обычно идут в хвосте развития стандарта.

Comment: @zenden2k  VS 12 - это уже вчерашний день.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow для больших проектов переход на новую версию студии бывает затруднителен. Сам я перепрыгнул с 2008 сразу на 2013, пришлось повозиться. Еще я пишу для 3х компиляторов, MSVC, gcc и clang, у них поддержка новых стандартов на разном уровне

Comment: @zenden2k  Я думаю, что это как раз связано с тем, что вы пропустили промежуточные выпуски компиляторов. Чем больше задержка, тем больше накапливается работы для рефакторинга.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow: Инициализатор вида `()` - это единственный инициализатор, который был всегда применим к массивам в `new[]` и в списках инициализации конструкторов еще со времен самого первого стандарта C++98.

Answer (score 4):

Если ваш компилятор поддерживает C++ 2011, то вы можете написать просто

```
static ullong *const M = new ullong[_n + 1] {};
```

В противном случае вы можете написать отдельную функцию для инициализации этого массива. Например,

```
inline ullong * init( uchar n )
{
    ullong *p = new ullong[n];

    std::memset( p, 0, n * sizeof( ullong ) );

    return p;
}
```

и

```
static ullong *const M = init( _n + 1 );
```

Или, опять-таки, если компилятор поддерживает, вы можете использовать лямбда-выражение, объявленное внутри функции перед объявлением static переменной. Например

```
auto l = []( uchar n ) -> ullong * 
{ 
    int *p = new ullong[n]; 
    return ( ullong * )std::memset( p, 0, n * sizeof( ullong ) );
};  
static ullong *const M = l( _n + 1 );
```

И не используйте идентификаторы, которые начинаются с символа подчеркивания или заканчиваются символом подчеркивания, а также идентификаторы, состоящие из одной заглавной буквы. Это плохой стиль программирования.